# Azure DocumentDB .NET SDK does not contains all HTTP Status Codes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

When you look at the document of HTTP status codes that CosmosDB REST API returns, there are some status codes that does not exist in .NET SDK.

[HTTP Status Codes for Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb)

Suppose, status code 449, does not exist in the HttpStatusCode(System.Net).

> "449 Retry With"
>
> The operation encountered a transient error.
>
> This only occurs on write operations.
>
> It is safe to retry the operation.

How do you handle this sort of status code using the Azure DocDb's .NET client SDK?

Or does the SDK handles these by itself?

Comment: Just compare the status to 449. HttpStatusCode is an enum, which means it's an integer with *some* predefined values. You can pass any integer to an enum. HttpStatusCode doesn't have predefined values for *all* status code, eg the funny ones like `418- I'm a teapot`

Comment: Actually, the value can be accessed only by the enum HttpStatusCode.
I tried finding the int value of the status code but no use.

Comment: That's not true. Just cast the result to an int. An enum *is* an integer. In fact the answer's code shows exactly this kind of casting

Comment: Oh, i got it. Thanks Panagiotis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, if we check the ***StatusCode*** property (that is nullable) of ***DocumentClientException***, we will find that status code 449 does not exist in the System.Net.HttpStatusCode.

[image]

After check the source of Azure DocumentDB .NET SDK, the SDK seems handle these by itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fred.
Gee, I totally forgot the existence of ILSpy...
I should of looked it up by ILSpy in the first place.
Guess, I got used to googling open source codes too much:-)